# Difference between rvm default and global gemset

Tags: ruby, rvm

I was on the default gemset on rvm. I then did a bundle install, and it did not install any gems since all of them had been installed.

I then switched to the global gemset; did a bundle install, and it started installing gems.

List of gemsets are:

```
root@dev:/home/karan/realestate# rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p195 (found in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195)
   (default)
=> global
```

I thought that the global and the default had the same gemset folder.

Comment: It can, but only when the default is the global gemset.  The purpose of the global gemset is to have a set of gems installed for all gemsets.  Default can be set to anything.  Including global.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Global is documented at rvm site - http://rvm.io/gemsets/global :

> Gems you install to the @global gemset for a given ruby are available to all other gemsets you create in association with that ruby.
>
> This is a good way to allow all of your projects to share the same installed gem for a specific ruby interpreter installation.

As for `default` it is just the gemset when you do not specify a gemset name, this is why it is listed in brackets in `rvm gemset list`:

```
gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p247 (found in /home/mpapis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247)
   (default)
   global
=> rvm-site
```

Where for both `(default)` and `rvm-site` all gems from `global` will be available.

You can select the `default` gemset by skipping the gemset name:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

or to switch to `default` of the current ruby - in case other was used:

```
rvm use @default
```

To access any gemset temporarily you can use:

```
rvm @global do gem install jist
```

This is especially useful for managing gems installed in `global` gemset - so those that will be available in all other gemsets of that ruby.

Comment: @mpapis:  can you update your answer a bit:  when I see (default) it's confusing to me--is that actually a completely different gemset all its own?

Comment: updated: `As for 'default' it is just the gemset when you do not specify a gemset name, this is why it is listed in brackets in rvm gemset list:`

Comment: I find that with rvm 1.25.14, `rvm use @default` does *not* go to `(default)`. Maybe that's because I've been changing the default with `rvm --default use ...`. `rvm use 2.0.0` *does* work to go back to the original `(default)` for a given Ruby interpreter.